# Unzip and store output name on a variable

Tags: shell, awk, variable, zip, macos

I have a zip file with always the same name : toto.zip
Inside there is only 1 file with the name who can change based on a version:  totoInstaller-20210321_titi.pkg

I would like to extract the name of the extracted file from a shell script (I'm on macOS) and store it on a variable to use it later ...
All I'm trying is not working... any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filename=$(unzip toto.zip | awk 'sub(/^[[:space:]]*inflating:[[:space:]]+/,""){print; exit}')
```

should work robustly and efficiently using any awk (but is untested). Also consider doing similar with the output of `unzip -l`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (although sometimes, there are differences between versions of `sed` and `unzip` available from one system to another):

```
filename=$(unzip toto.zip | sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*inflating:[[:space:]]*//p')
```

This command unzips the file and send the output to `sed`. `sed` looks for lines starting with whitespace and then `inflating:` . If such a line is found, sed will delete everthing up to and including the `inflating:` and any subsequent whitespace and then it will print what is left, which should be the file name. Everything else is discarded (thanks to option `-n`). Finally, we store the output in variable `filename`.

Comment: I don't think that `sed` will work on [macOS](https://ss64.com/osx/sed.html). Try this one instead: `sed -n '/inflating: /s/[[:space:]]*inflating:[[:space:]]*\(.*\)$/\1/p`.

Comment: But there is no need to match twice or to include the rest of the line. It should be enough to do `sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*inflating:[[:space:]]*//p'`

Comment: @terdon Hmm, I should stop answering questions for other OSes involving sed... I initially captured the filename in a group because of possible trailing whitespaces but finally decided against it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, both sed & awk worked even if they both let an extra space at the end to trim

Why using unzip -l here?